# JavaScript - Detect Certificate Errors within an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I'm wondering if it is possible to detect cert errors within an iframe.

The plan is to make the frame invisible unless a certificate error comes up, in Which case it will display the frame so the user can accept it.

This will need to work in IE though

Comment: do you have control over the iframe, or is the iframe something you are serving, where you can modify its source code? If you did and wanted to get clever, you may be able to use the Window.postMessage() capabilities so that you know what is happening in the iframe but that would require you to have some control over modifying the source code in the iframe. Else, your options are limited, if the domain the iframe is on is cross-origin, then there will be security restrictions preventing access to it.

Comment: Sadly, realized after I posted that what I'm trying to do is impossible, which is a shame as all sites involved are on an intranet

Comment: yea, accessing cross-origin resources is a big security no, no.

Comment: Shame I can't in this instance as everything involved is on an intranet